# How to solve this pop-up message error issue?

Tags: r

[image: Screenshot]

> Error in fetch(key) : lazy-load database
> 'C:/Users/RIDDHIMA/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/ggplot2/help/ggplot2.rdb'
> is corruptyt

I am getting the above message popped-up over again everytime I try to write a code in R script,and this happening only with the RStudio Desktop application. What is the solution to it?

I was expecting a smooth R application functioning but getting the above error message popped_up over again.

Comment: Please try to uninstall and reinstall the ggplot2 package.

Comment: R messages are sometimes cryptic and even after years of working with the R/RStudio ecosystem, I only can positively understand a couple of these messages. So ... do not despair. Often things can be reset by restarting your session or starting RStudio again. Also check the different colours of your code, try to understand what you load/View etc. and why to put "" or not. A good practice is to load all libraries before doing anything else (ncluding loading data). Last but not least, corruption often require a reinstallation, aka `install.packages(...)` . As Eva highlighted, reinstall ggplot2